# Naming conventions for 32 vs 64 bit Windows installer

Tags: windows, installation, architecture, naming-conventions

If you release software with both a 32 bit and 64 bit installer, what is the correct standard convention to follow?

For example, if you look at some of the top applications on sourceforge, you come up with a verity of names

- win32 vs win64
- x32 vs x64
- x86 vs x86-64
- x86-32 vs x86-64
- and a bunch others

What is correct?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity; `32-bit` or `64-Bit`.

Microsoft is using that nomenclature for [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications) itself, so I'd use that.

Historically, `x86` and `x64` have been used; however those numbers are only meaningful to those that understand the relevance of Intel's 80x86 processor naming convention from waaaaayyyyyyy back in the day.

(great username by the way)